# Open source video editing software compatible with Linux

Tags: editing, software-recommendation, effects, special-effects

I've been looking around for open source software I can use to quickly edit some of my projects when I'm away from home on my Linux laptop and the best I've found so far is Blender.

Does anyone else have any recommendations for open source software? FX software recommendations would also be welcome.

Comment: Welcome Aut0 :) Please ask a new question on VFX and what exactly do you want to achieve - asking multiple questions is not allowed here. In general there is Blender and Natron. I'd also recommend you to read this article for NLE's: http://opensource.com/life/15/1/current-state-linux-video-editing. Anyway, enjoy video.se!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Light Works is supposed to be pretty good. It's been used on some pretty big budget projects so it's definitely worth a look. I have tried it myself though.

https://www.lwks.com/

**EDIT** 
This is *not* open source software but it *is* freely available.

Comment: is lightworks open source?

Comment: My mistake. No it's not open source but it is freely available for download.

Comment: Ok, please add this to the answer, otherwise it's misleading.